# Registry Entry for Automatic (Delayed Start) on Windows

Tags: windows, service, registry, startup

I am trying to set a Windows Service to DelayedStart from the command line. I am using this syntax:

```
REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\MSSQL$EXPRESS2012 /v Start /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f
REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\MSSQL$EXPRESS2012 /v DelayedAutostart /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

However, in the Services tab (SERVICES.MSC) it still shows up as Automatic, not Delayed Start.

Is there some other super secret Registry value that needs to be set?  I am using Windows 7 x64

Comment: I see that the SC command is the correct way to do this.  But it would still be good to know the Registry values involved.

Comment: The official way to set a service to delayed start is with the [`ChangeServiceConfig2()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681988.aspx) function, using the [`SERVICE_DELAYED_AUTO_START_INFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685155.aspx) struct. As the documentation says, changing the setting does not take effect until after a system reboot.